# Getting ClassNotFoundException Failed to find Datasource while connecting to cassandra (write)

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, cloudera-cdh, spark-cassandra-connector

I have hundreds of spark jobs running in parallel, in a cloudera cluster, writing to a Cassandra cluster throughout the day. EveryDay, a few fail with below error generally when cluster is stressed in a multi-tenant env, which run fine on a subsequent rerun without having to make any modifications in the spark jobs.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:635)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:241)
    at my.code.CassandraWriter$.writeDataframeToDC(CassandraWriter.scala:43)
    at my.code.CassandraWriter$.writeDataframe(CassandraWriter.scala:18)
    at scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$ParArrayIterator.foreach_quick(ParArray.scala:143)
    at scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$ParArrayIterator.foreach(ParArray.scala:136)
    at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Foreach.leaf(ParIterableLike.scala:972)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply$mcV$sp(Tasks.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$class.tryLeaf(Tasks.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Foreach.tryLeaf(ParIterableLike.scala:969)
    at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$class.compute(Tasks.scala:152)
    at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.compute(Tasks.scala:443)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:160)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
    at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:618)
```

My Project jar is not a fat jar. 
The datastax dependency jar is available at given path with name as below:

```
.../distributedLibs/spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.3.0.jar
```

The idea is only distributedLibs folder jars get distributed over cluster node and all lib folder jars get added to classpath while spark-submit. This is to reduce the space required by spark job working directories on the cluster nodes.

My spark-submit command is as below:

```
sparks-submit
    --jars "${distributedLib_classpath}" \
    --driver-class-path ${distributedLib_classpath} \
    --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=${distributedLib_classpath} \
```

Please suggest what might be causing this issue, and why does this work on rerun? How can I ensure there are no such failures?

Generally, a failure occurs when many jobs are running in parallel on cluster causing race condition for resources.

Comment: I would say that this some issue with classpath, etc. It depends how you're starting them, how they are built (fat jar or not), etc.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is about you missing that jar in your packaged jar file. Make sure your dependencies have `<scope>compile</scope>` in them.

Comment: I am not using a fat jar, but have added the absolute jar path (cloudera cluster) in --confspark.driver.extraClassPath and spark.executore.extraClassPath in my spark-submit.

Comment: I am more confused that why would it work fine most of the times, and, even failed ones run fine on rerun. Generally, a failure occurs when many jobs are running in parallel on cluster causing race condition for resources.

Answer (score 1):

Some time very small issue:

1. if using maven and trying to run in IDE itself then make sure you remove provided tag(`<scope>provided</scope>`):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.5.0</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: maven coordinates are incorrect.  Plus the `spark-submit` is used, it's a different case

Comment: What if some one  don't want to manage dependency externally, and want to use the one which is in pom only to make version in sync. It's just another missing point which generally missed. Possible this in not correct thread but I just posted if this also can be cause.